# "Time To Lock" in Bit Timing Synchronisation

Tags: digital-communications, timing, synchronization

In the context of bit timing synchronisation in digital communications, what is meant by the requirement that says the "Time to lock to a sampling point should be no more than X symbols"?

There seems to be no information about this issue online.

Comment: How about adding some links to the information you found online? Many communication systems include in each transmission a preamble designed for the synchronization system to lock on before the data (the payload) is actually transmitted. If this preamble is $X$ symbols long, the time for the synchronization subsystem to lock on should be _no more_ than the time duration needed to transmit $X$ symbols on the channel, no?

Comment: It was a typo, I meant to say "There seems to be NO information about this online".I have now fixed that.

Comment: @DilipSarwate I think understand now.Does the receiver usually know what the X symbols in the preamble will be or does the transmitter just create a preamble that it knows the receiver will easily synchronise with? e.g A preamble with a high density of transitions.

Comment: The preamble has high density of transitions and is known at the receiver. Depending on the application, the transmitter may have, say, 10 different preambles that are used repeatedly in a fixed cyclic order (#1, then #2, then #3, etc) or it may have just one preamble that is always used (which helps if packet #3 is lost, etc).